# Angular $compile cant find directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a current project based around single-page-applications (SPA) and wanted to implent a function that dynamically loads directives into my html based on which kind of SPA is required.

The relevant code for that is:

1. the part of my controller that should load the directive

   ```
   function checkSpaType(x) {
   if (x === "quiz") {
       const directivePosition = document.getElementById("spa");
       directivePosition.append($compile("<quizSPA></quizSPA>")($scope));
     };
   };
   ```
2. the directive itself

   ```
   function quizDirective () {
    return {
     templateUrl: "templates/quizSPA.html",
     controller: 'quizCtrl',
     link: function quizSPA() {}
           }
   }
   ```

and of course it doesnt work as planned. 
After I run the scripts the only thing that gets loaded in my HTML is the message
"[object HTMLUnknownElement]]"
iam very sure that angular just cant find my directive, but how do I make it visible to it?

Also the template folder is in the same folder as my index.html from where the site starts. So that shouldnt be a problem. Likewise I already tried renaming the tags I load the in the html, sadly to no effect.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Okay after some digging I found atleast part of the problem.
My script definetly finds the directive.
I split my code and saved the $compile in a variable, logged the variable and only then appended the variable to my html.
While still only the message "[[object HTMLUnknownElement]]" gets loaded into my html, digging into the log bore some fruit.
The log shows that the logged variable, that later gets appended, contains childnodes which contain my directive.
So the problem has to be that either compile isnt compiling as supposed or append not appending as supposed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself right now.

Had to change:

```
directivePosition.append($compile("<quiz-s-p-a></quiz-s-p-a>")($scope))
```

to:

```
const spaDirective = $compile("<quiz>")($scope);
      directivePosition.append(spaDirective[0]);
```